# Implementing string variables from an interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a wrapper that inherits from an interface.  I have been able to implement the methods from the interface with no problem but when I try to do it for the string variables I keep getting the following error:

> Does not implement interface member XXX

Implementation:

```
    public string FilterGridId()
    {
        return _WrappedHelper.FilterGridId;
    }

    public string Id()
    {
        return _WrappedHelper.Id;
    }

    public string PagerId()
    {
        return _WrappedHelper.PagerId;
    }
```

String variables from the interface:

```
    string FilterGridId { get; }
    string Id { get; }
    string PagerId { get; }
```

What is the proper way to implement these?

Comment: You interface defines properties, but you try to implement them with methods which clearly will not match - see Hamlet Hakobyan answer for correct code.

Comment: The `()` in my codes was a test to try and make it work, the first time I coded it I did not use them as methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have in you words variables in your interface. They are properties which you can implement as:

```
public string FilterGridId
{
   get { return _WrappedHelper.FilterGridId; }
}

public string Id
{
   get { return _WrappedHelper.Id; }
}

public string PagerId
{
   get { return _WrappedHelper.PagerId; }
}
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that and it failed but this time it is working. Thanks.